# The accept answer & favourite button are bugging my user experience

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

Edit: Bump

[image]

As you may be able to see in the above image the accept answer button is too far to the right, the active accept answer button (the green one) is perfectly fine.

The reason for this is because it is misplaced in the [image source](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ux/img/sprites.svg).

The same can be said for both the active and inactive favourite buttons, these are however placed too far to the left (by 1 pixel).

One may also argue that the circles are also not the same, but that's (possibly) for another post ;) (don't worry I'm not actually going to).

Answer (score 1):

That's a strangely good catch. But I'd have to disagree with the *too far to the right* part :P

Like you mentioned correctly, the problem is in the sprite. Hope the designers will update it.